# Changing OS X behaviour after crash recovery

Tags: macos, crash, recovery

OS X tends to try and help out and reopen everything to just the way it was before it crashed. I mean this in two ways:

1. If an app running within OS X crashes, OS X will remember the last working state of the app and resume at that point next time you launch the app.

   Example: Safari crashes because I've shamelessly opened way too many tabs and windows again. The next time I launch Safari I tax the system severely and fight to be able close windows or even force quit again.
2. If OS X itself crashes, the computer automatically restarts and loads OS X again, at which point every application, web page, and document that was open at time are simultaneously reloaded.

How can I prevent or alter the way such situations are handled?

Answer (score 1):

To your first question:

Open System Preference -General settings, and select following:

[image: do not open]

To your second question: (actually we do not like to have more than one question, but since they are related...) that is a Safari settings.